# How would I separate queries in the same file

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm really struggling with this. I have a viewdetails.php page, addnew.php page and a php.php. The php.php page has my query for both pages. First I have the query that displays results on viewdetails.php and second is the query that displays results on addnew.php page. The problem I'm having is when I open addnew.php in a browser it gives me errors regarding the path to dbandpassword.php and for other items in the query for viewdetails.php.

How do I keep all these queries in one page (php.php) and keep them separate so I don't get errors? Should I be combining the two queries together or maybe just some of it together? I know the code needs to be cleaned up, I'm not worried about that right now. I also know that the queries both work individually if put in their own file (php.php, php2.php).

```
 <?php

 ob_start(); 
 require("../admin/dbandpassword.php");
 ob_end_clean(); 

// FETCH LEAD INFORMATION - this is query for viewdetails.php

 $query = ("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE contacttype IN ('Buyer','Seller','Buyer / Seller','Investor') AND leadstatus = 'New' ORDER BY date DESC");

$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli,$query));
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

$firstname = $row ['firstname'];     
$lastname = $row['lastname'];
$ID = $row['ID'];   
$partner  = $row['spousefirst'];   
$phonecell = $row['phonecell'];
$email = $row['email'];
$date = $row['date'];
$contacttype = $row['contacttype'];
$agentassigned = $row['agentassigned'];
$leadstatus = $row['leadstatus'];

echo'
     <table>
     <tbody>       
     <tr>
        <td width="10"><input type="checkbox" name="" id="" value="'.$ID.'"></td>
        <td><a href="/backend/leads/view/?ID='.$ID.'"><strong>'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'</strong></a></td>
        <td><a href="/backend/leads/view/?ID='. $ID.'">'.$partner.'</a></td>
        <td>'.$phonecell.'</td>
        <td><a href="mailto:'. $email.'">'.$email.'</a></td>
        <td>'.date("M jS, g:i A", strtotime($date)).'</td>
        <td>'.$contacttype.'</td>
        <td>'.$agentassigned.'</td>
        <td>'.$leadstatus.'</td>
        <td><a href="/backend/contacts/notes.php?ID='.$ID.'">View </a>+</td>
        <td><a href="/backend/contacts/todo.php?ID='.$ID.'">View </a>+</td>
        <td><a href="/backend/contacts/deletesuccess.php?ID='.$ID.'">D</a></td>
       </tr>
       </tbody>
       </table>';
         }

// ADD LEAD - this would be for addnew.php page

       if (isset($_POST['firstname']))
       {

       require("../../admin/dcandpassword.php"); // NOTE THE DIFFERENT PATH THAN ABOVE BECAUSE addnew.php IS A FOLDER DEEPER

       $ID = $_POST['ID'];
       $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['NOW()']);
       $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['firstname']);
       $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['lastname']);
       $spousefirst = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['spousefirst']);
       $spouselast = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['spouselast']);
       $primarybday = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['primarybday']);
       $spousebday = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['spousebday']);
       $phonecell = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['phonecell']);
       $phonehome = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['phonehome']);
       $phoneoffice = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['phoneoffice']);
       $spousecell = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['spousecell']);
       $phoneother = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['phoneother']);
       $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['email']);
       $emailspouse = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['emailspouse']);
       $emailother = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['emailother']);
       $emailspouseother = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['emailspouseother']);
       $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['address']);
       $suite = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['suite']);
       $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['city']);
       $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['state']);
       $zipcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['zipcode']);
       $addressother = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['addressother']);
       $suiteother = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['suiteother']);
       $cityother = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli$_POST['cityother']);
       $stateother = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['stateother']);
       $zipcodeother = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['zipcodeother']);
       $agentassigned = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['agentassigned']);
       $contacttype = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['contacttype']);
       $contactstatus = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['contactstatus']);
       $leadstatus = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['leadstatus']);
       $contactsource = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['contactsource']);
       $timing = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['timing']);
       $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
       $subscribesearches = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['subscribesearches']);
       $subscribedrips = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['subscribedrips']);

       $query = ("INSERT INTO contacts (date, firstname, lastname, spousefirst, spouselast, primarybday, spousebday, phonecell, phonehome, phoneoffice, spousecell, phoneother, email, emailspouse, emailother, emailspouseother, address, suite, city, state, zipcode, addressother, suiteother, cityother, stateother, zipcodeother, agentassigned, contacttype, contactstatus, leadstatus, contactsource, timing, password, subscribesearches, subscribedrips) VALUES (NOW(), '$firstname', '$lastname', '$spousefirst', '$spouselast', '$primarybday', '$spousebday', '$phonecell', '$phonehome', '$phoneoffice', '$spousecell', '$phoneother', '$email', '$emailspouse', '$emailother', '$emailspouseother', '$address', '$suite', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$addressother', '$suiteother', '$cityother', '$stateother', '$zipcodeother', '$agentassigned', '$contacttype', '$contactstatus', '$leadstatus', '$contactsource', '$timing', '$password', '$subscribesearches', '$subscribedrips')");

       mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));

       header("location: http://www.mydomain.com/backend/leads/edit/?ID=".mysqli_insert_id($mysqli));

  exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really do need to worry about more than just separating the queries, but they appear to be independent of one another (one is an INSERT and one is a SELECT, and they aren't part of a transaction).

The real error here is probably that you're requiring the same file twice on a page which is both needless and risky. Delete the second require statement.

Comment: Okay, well I'm learning :) I removed the second require statement so that error is gone. When I open addnew.php the `<table>` from the SELECT query shows up, how do I stop that from happening? What else should I be worried about? Thanks!

Comment: Above the echo code [for the table], do something like this: `if (!isset($_POST['firstname']))`. (Wrap the echo statement in an if block like that). Since firstname is present if the form was submitted, it'll hide the table. You should really separate these actions into multiple PHP files, and above that; you should separate your view code from your business logic. See [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: Thanks David. I've been trying to understand this, when you say separate view code from business logic do you mean I should create a new page table.php and then do an include in the query? Could I put the table in the original page viewdetails.php which has all the other HTML? I've tried this but get errors. Thanks again for your help, I'm really trying get an understanding of this and a lot of the forums are hard to understand.

Comment: Not exactly. You probably shouldn't be following PHP's "everything-is-a-template-let's-dive-into-scripting" idea. A big key to PHP projects (and projects in every facet of life) is organization. You should have a controller which runs the query, gets the result, and then includes a template, passing along the data. Perform no data queries or business logic in your view, only UI-related logic.

Comment: So a MODEL would be a query in model.php, a CONTROLLER would be my echo statements in controller.php and VIEW would be my html that uses includes/requires to display the echos in index.php? Am I reading this right?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think so. The controller shouldn't output anything. It should use your model to run the query and then include the template which would display the output.

Comment: I'm really trying to get a picture of this: So MODEL.php would have `$fname = $_POST['fname']`, the CONTROLLER.php would have `include(MODEL.php); $query="INSERT INTO table (firstname) VALUES ('John'); include(VIEW.php);` and VIEW.php would have `echo'.$firstname.'`? That doesn't make sense, so I know I'm wrong, can you give me any examples?

Comment: found this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022231/simple-php-mvc-example